# B2B runtime error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, exception, bouncycastle, b2b

I am using  `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())` in B2B callout when my code reaches at  `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())` call it gives the following exception.

```
<Aug 25, 2015 10:06:40 AM AST> <Error> <oracle.soa.b2b.engine> <BEA-000000> <Error -:  B2B-50029:  B2B runtime error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`enter code here`
    at oracle.tip.b2b.callout.B2BCalloutHandler.handleOutgoingCallout(B2BCalloutHandler.java:583)
    at oracle.tip.b2b.msgproc.Request.outgoingRequestPostColab(Request.java:1654)
    at oracle.tip.b2b.msgproc.Request.outgoingRequest(Request.java:1121)
    at oracle.tip.b2b.engine.Engine.processOutgoingMessageImpl(Engine.java:1666)
    at oracle.tip.b2b.engine.Engine.processOutgoingMessage(Engine.java:830)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.b2b.B2BReference.postProcess(B2BReference.java:486)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.b2b.B2BReference.request(B2BReference.java:216)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.mesh.SynchronousMessageHandler.doRequest(SynchronousMessageHandler.java:139)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.mesh.MessageRouter.request(MessageRouter.java:182)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.mesh.MeshImpl.request(MeshImpl.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at oracle.integration.platform.metrics.PhaseEventAspect.invoke(PhaseEventAspect.java:71)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy358.request(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.fabric.CubeServiceEngine.requestToMesh(CubeServiceEngine.java:858)
    at com.collaxa.cube.ws.WSInvocationManager.invoke(WSInvocationManager.java:267)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.ext.common.InvokeHandler.__invoke(InvokeHandler.java:1099)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.ext.common.InvokeHandler.handleNormalInvoke(InvokeHandler.java:594)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.ext.common.InvokeHandler.handle(InvokeHandler.java:132)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.model.runtime.microinstructions.MIInvoke.doExecute(MIInvoke.java:42)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.microkernel.MIBase.execute(MIBase.java:34)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.microkernel.MISequenceBlock.doExecute(MISequenceBlock.java:68)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.microkernel.MIBase.execute(MIBase.java:34)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.microkernel.MicroInstructionContext.callMicroInstruction(MicroInstructionContext.java:201)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.microkernel.MICall.doExecute(MICall.java:38)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.microkernel.MIBase.execute(MIBase.java:34)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.microkernel.MISequenceBlock.doExecute(MISequenceBlock.java:68)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.microkernel.MIBase.execute(MIBase.java:34)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.microkernel.MicroInstructionContext.callMicroInstruction(MicroInstructionContext.java:201)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.microkernel.MicroInstructionContext.callProcedure(MicroInstructionContext.java:208)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.microkernel.MicroInstructionContext.executeProcedure(MicroInstructionContext.java:325)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.model.runtime.MIBPMNActivityWMP.executeProcedure(MIBPMNActivityWMP.java:396)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.model.runtime.MIBPMNActivityWMP.__executeStatements(MIBPMNActivityWMP.java:313)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.ext.bpel.common.wmp.BaseBPELActivityWMP.perform(BaseBPELActivityWMP.java:173)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.CubeEngine.performActivity(CubeEngine.java:2718)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.CubeEngine._handleWorkItem(CubeEngine.java:1197)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.CubeEngine.handleWorkItem(CubeEngine.java:1100)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.dispatch.message.instance.PerformMessageHandler.handleLocal(PerformMessageHandler.java:76)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.dispatch.DispatchHelper.handleLocalMessage(DispatchHelper.java:251)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.dispatch.DispatchHelper.sendMemory(DispatchHelper.java:330)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.CubeEngine.endRequest(CubeEngine.java:4652)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.CubeEngine.endRequest(CubeEngine.java:4583)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.CubeEngine._callbackPerformer(CubeEngine.java:1411)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.CubeEngine.callbackPerformer(CubeEngine.java:1340)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.delivery.DeliveryHelper.callbackPerformer(DeliveryHelper.java:396)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.delivery.DeliveryService.handleCallback(DeliveryService.java:812)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.delivery.DeliveryService.handleCallback(DeliveryService.java:722)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.ejb.impl.CubeDeliveryBean.handleCallback(CubeDeliveryBean.java:359)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.jee.spi.MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.visit(MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.java:37)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.callback(EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.java:54)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.jee.spi.EnvironmentInterceptor.invoke(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:50)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy275.handleCallback(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.ejb.impl.BPMNDeliveryBean_of8dk6_ICubeDeliveryLocalBeanImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionLocalMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionLocalMethodInvoker.java:39)
    at oracle.bpm.bpmn.engine.ejb.impl.BPMNDeliveryBean_of8dk6_ICubeDeliveryLocalBeanImpl.handleCallback(Unknown Source)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.dispatch.message.instance.CallbackDeliveryMessageHandler.handle(CallbackDeliveryMessageHandler.java:45)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.dispatch.DispatchHelper.handleMessage(DispatchHelper.java:141)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.dispatch.BaseDispatchTask.process(BaseDispatchTask.java:89)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.dispatch.BaseDispatchTask.run(BaseDispatchTask.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at com.collaxa.cube.engine.dispatch.Dispatcher$ContextCapturingThreadFactory$2.run(Dispatcher.java:933)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at oracle.tip.b2b.callout.B2BCalloutHandler.handleOutgoingCallout(B2BCalloutHandler.java:569)
    ... 86 more
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at oracle.tip.b2b.callout.B2BCalloutHandler.handleOutgoingCallout(B2BCalloutHandler.java:569)
    at oracle.tip.b2b.msgproc.Request.outgoingRequestPostColab(Request.java:1654)
    at oracle.tip.b2b.msgproc.Request.outgoingRequest(Request.java:1121)
    at oracle.tip.b2b.engine.Engine.processOutgoingMessageImpl(Engine.java:1666)
    at oracle.tip.b2b.engine.Engine.processOutgoingMessage(Engine.java:830)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.b2b.B2BReference.postProcess(B2BReference.java:486)
    at oracle.integration.platform.blocks.b2b.B2BReference.request(B2BReference.ja
```

Comment: You are trying to access the first char of an empty String (containing 0 chars) or something similar

Comment: HI, I don't know where to look in code for this exception because I am getting this exception when my program reaches to Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()) function. Can you please help me about it?

Comment: Wouldn't know how. I don't know your code, I don't know which classes mentioned in the stacktrace are written by you and which are not. But normally, it should tell you exactly where the problem occurs. Possibly, you are passing an invalid parameter somewhere.